# Cassandra ordered result of a range query

Tags: cassandra, cql, date-range

I have the following table:

```
create table tweets_by_hashtags(
    hashtag text,
    tweet_id text,
    tweet_posted_time timestamp,
    retweet_count int,
    body text,
    primary key(hashtag, tweet_id)
 )
```

I want to perform the following query; and I need the result to be order by retweet_count desc

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tweets_by_hashtags 
where 
    hashtag = 'some_hashtag' and
    tweet_posted_time >= 'from_time' and
    tweet_posted_time < 'to_time'
```

please help me with the design of the primary/partition/clustering keys.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need your data to be partitioned by hashtag and ordered by time as well (you are doing range queries so you need to know between which times certain tweets happened) your table should be created like this:

```
create table tweets_by_hashtags(
    hashtag text,
    tweet_id text,
    tweet_posted_time timestamp,
    retweet_count int,
    body text,
    primary key((hashtag), tweet_posted_time, tweet_id)
 )
```

Where `hashtag` is partition key and tweets are clustered first by time (ordering by time which is enabling range queries) and `tweet_id` is added for uniqueness (if two tweets happen at same exact time you need to differentiate them).

This will enable select query as you proposed where you need tweets by hashtag between some start and end time.

As for other part of the question I see two possible solutions:

**1. Order on application level**

When you pull your list of tweets you can loop through list and order by retweet count, this way you will have ordered tweets between times you want.

**2. Fixed time buckets**

If you have resolution you need, i.e. daily tweets, hourly tweets or something and you can skip range criteria in your query you can create your table with composite primary key composed of hashtag and time resolution and use retweet count as clustering key.

```
create table hourly_tweets_by_hashtags(
        hashtag text,
        tweet_id text,
        tweet_posted_time timestamp,
        tweet_posted_date text,
        tweet_posted_hour int,
        retweet_count int,
        body text,
        primary key((tweet_posted_date, tweet_posted_hour, hashtag), retweet_count, tweet_id)
     ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (retweet_count DESC)
```

Now your composite primary key is composed of date, hour in day and hashtag and tweets are ordered by `retweet_count`. Again `tweet_id` is added because of uniqueness.

Now you can do query like this:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    hourly_tweets_by_hashtags 
where 
    hashtag = 'some_hashtag' and
    tweet_posted_date = '22/01/2016' and
    tweet_posted_hour = 16;
```

and this query will return all tweets on certain date at 16h ordered by `retweet_count`. Clustering order is added to put most retweets on top.